# Debian Buster: cgmanager fails, but why?

Tags: debian, cgroups

System is Debian Buster - I am trying to get cgroups to work, following what documentation I have been able to find online (mainly [Redhat's Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch01)), but I have a problem:

```
# systemctl status cgmanager
● cgmanager.service - Cgroup management daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cgmanager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-07-01 07:20:57 UTC; 1h 13min ago
  Process: 416 ExecStart=/sbin/cgmanager -m name=systemd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 416 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 01 07:20:56 cgroups systemd[1]: cgmanager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 01 07:20:57 cgroups systemd[1]: cgmanager.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jul 01 07:20:57 cgroups systemd[1]: cgmanager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 01 07:20:57 cgroups systemd[1]: Stopped Cgroup management daemon.
Jul 01 07:20:57 cgroups systemd[1]: cgmanager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 01 07:20:57 cgroups systemd[1]: cgmanager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 01 07:20:57 cgroups systemd[1]: Failed to start Cgroup management daemon.
```

an `strace` on cgmanager shows:

```
# strace -o cgmanager.trc -f /sbin/cgmanager -m name=systemd
...
604   mkdir("/run", 0755)               = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
604   mkdir("/run/cgmanager", 0755)     = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
604   mkdir("/run/cgmanager/fs", 0755)  = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
604   mkdir("/run/cgmanager/agents", 0755) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
604   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/cgroup", O_RDONLY) = 4
604   fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
604   read(4, "11:cpu,cpuacct:/\n10:cpuset:/\n9:d"..., 1024) = 316
604   close(4)                          = 0
604   mkdir("/sys/fs/cgroup/.cgm_unified", 0755) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
604   mount("cgroup", "/sys/fs/cgroup/.cgm_unified", "cgroup", 0, "__DEVEL__sane_behavior") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
604   write(2, "cgmanager: Error mounting unifie"..., 62) = 62
604   write(2, "cgmanager: failed to collect cgr"..., 47) = 47
604   exit_group(1)                     = ?
604   +++ exited with 1 +++
```

Perhaps the problem is that I can't find any good, up-to-date documentation for how to do this on a recent Debian system. Do I need cgmanager at all in Debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you link is for RedHat 6 which would have a very old kernel (kernel version 2.6.32 from 2010) and none of the recent `cgroup` updates that would be included in Debian Buster (kernel version 4.19 from 2019).

I believe RedHat 6 only had Control Groups v1 available while there is now also Control Groups v2 to choose from.  The [Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation) for [`cgroups-v1`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt) and [`cgroups-v2`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt) may be a better resource than the posted RedHat one.  If you like RedHat documentation, the [RedHat 8 docs about using Control Groups for application limits](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/setting-limits-for-applications_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel) would be a closer representation of your Debian Buster kernel.

By default, most `systemd` systems are already using `cgroups` so they should be working already (you can check with `mount | grep cgroup`).  As for if you need `cgmanager`, that would mostly depend on what you plan on doing with `cgroup`s and if `cgmanager` makes handling that easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer - I've been search wide and far but most of what I found was out of date (and undated as well). I don't particularly like Redhat, but in this case their documentation seemed to be the most coherent; I was only looking at cgmanager because their docs mention it, really.